C# NetworkStream.ReadyAsync have different behaviour on different pc
I have a C# program that connects to a device, let's say 192.168.0.10:10000 via TCP.
I have a TcpListener that receives on the same port and a NetworkStream that reads what I receive from the connected device.
I use stream.ReadAsync to read data from the device, I have the software installed on 4 different computers, some windows and some linux.
When I restart the 192.168.0.10, the connections should close and then reconnect, on the Windows devices I have it works, on Linux works on some devices and on some others devices not, I can't understand why
On devices where everything works, this line returns 0:
await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cToken);

and then I close the connection, but on the Linux PC where it doesn't work the code remains stuck here until I try to write something in the TcpClient, with a consequent exception.
Why does ReadAsync behave differently depending on the PC it runs on?

is this a zero-length read? i.e. is buffer.Length zero? also: can we see the code at the other end of the connection? iyou're trying to detect an EOF, so: if we can see the socket being closed or half-closed (for send), that would be great

No buffer.length is not 0, I check if ReadAsync return 0 or the length of the bytes actually been read, if 0 I close the stream/connection and then reset the connection to the device.
I don't own the code of the devices that is manually restarted on my tests, It's a third-part device.

Looks like a bug of the third-part device, this device have 2 network cards and one the first net-card send the TCP FIN packet meanwhile the seconds one doesn't send it, does the ReadAsync relies on the TCP FIN packet in order to return 0 and consider the connection closed by the client?

without a FIN, it hasn't been closed, so it is correct to not report EOF

You need a network capture to see what's actually gonin on.
